# How do I input a calculation into MessageBox in C#

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to calculate the "change" due at the end of my program into a MessageBox. The Dollar amount entered into a text box needs to have the total subtracted from it but I just can't seem to see what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me finish this?

```
namespace HardwareStore
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ProductBox.Items.Add(new Hardware() { ItemNo = 1010, ProdName = "Hammer         ", Price = (decimal)14.99d });
            ProductBox.Items.Add(new Hardware() { ItemNo = 1056, ProdName = "Bag of Nails   ", Price = (decimal)19.99d });
            ProductBox.Items.Add(new Hardware() { ItemNo = 2001, ProdName = "Saw               ", Price = (decimal)29.99d });
            ProductBox.Items.Add(new Hardware() { ItemNo = 2005, ProdName = "Chainsaw       ", Price = (decimal)69.99d });
            ProductBox.Items.Add(new Hardware() { ItemNo = 3090, ProdName = "Ladder          ", Price = (decimal)109.99d });
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text); i++)
                    ReceiptBox.Items.Add(ProductBox.Items[ProductBox.SelectedIndex]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ReceiptBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            decimal subTotal = ReceiptBox.Items.Cast<Hardware>().Sum(item => item.Price);
            decimal tax = Math.Round((subTotal * .075M), 2);
            decimal total = subTotal + tax;

            lblSub.Text = "$" + subTotal.ToString();
            lblTax.Text = "$" + tax.ToString();
            lblTotal.Text = "$" + total.ToString();

            lblSub.Visible = true;
            lblTax.Visible = true;
            lblTotal.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Change Due: $  ");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong? you didnt say that

Comment: Have you even searched the internet on how to format a string, or even learn a bit about the different variable scopes?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am a beginner and have been doing a lot of searching. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I caught it twice...

```
decimal total = 0; //declare the total as global variable
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        decimal subTotal = ReceiptBox.Items.Cast<Hardware>().Sum(item => item.Price);
        decimal tax = Math.Round((subTotal * .075M), 2);
        total = subTotal + tax;

        lblSub.Text = "$" + subTotal.ToString();
        lblTax.Text = "$" + tax.ToString();
        lblTotal.Text = "$" + total.ToString();

        lblSub.Visible = true;
        lblTax.Visible = true;
        lblTotal.Visible = true;
    }

 private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     decimal customerPay = 100;

     if (total != 0){
             decimal changeDue = customerPay - total;

             txtDollar.Txt = "$ " + changeDue.toString();

             MessageBox.Show("Change Due: " + txtDollar.Txt);
     }


 }
```

Comment: No, I want to display just the change due from the total.

Comment: I need to due the calculation of total minus what is entered into a text box called txtdollars.

Comment: Then calculate your change due and enter it into a textbox called txtdollars and do the same thing like the above

Comment: Can you show me what you mean and where I put this?

Comment: Check the updated answer to see is it what you want?

Comment: I really appreciate your help! But, the problem is that the items that end up in the total are not fixed nor is the txtDollars.

Comment: I do not know how much the customer will pay. If the bill adds up to 350.00 I can not say customerPay 100

Comment: If you don't know how much your customer will Pay, then how can you manage to know how much is the changeDue? =.=